# Should equals be burdened by the business logic of the application?

Tags: java, scala, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

Let's say we have such classes in the Java project:

```
@Entity
class Person {
  @Id
  String internalId;
  @OneToMany
  Set<Profession> profession;
}

@Entity
class Profession {
  @Id
  String id;
  String professionName;
  Integer yearsOfPractise;
}
```

In the business logic the `professionName` has to be unique per Person.

Is it correct to `@override` the `equals` with taking into the account only the `professionName` field and ingoring the others?

On the one hand such the equals can be handy if this class is handled from the business logic perspective. But such equals can be completely wrong and unhandy in cases when this class will have to be handled from some different perspective.

How to decide it?

Comment: I'd say: Think about your usecase. Decide. Document.  Your class is an object/ an entity. If  professionName is criteria enough for your object to decide equality, than it is. Everyone who uses it has to use the Object the way you defined it can be used.  It is like that: you are never able to create a perfect code for every scenario. You create perfect code for your scenario.

Comment: Well originally I thought that equals should evere time compare all of the attributes for equality and that equals should be always related isolately to the class and not to the business logic. Because the business logic is too volatile. Am I wrong about it?

Comment: But let's take a look on the examle I've provided. As the application will grow up and will contains thousands lines of code, the Profession class can be reused f or some different purpose. And for this purpose the equals comparing only `professionName` will be not yet suitable. And you will be unable to change the old equals. What to do then? You will maybe have to create entire new Profession class and maybe also new table in the database and the reason will be the equals which is too much concrete for some specific business logic case.

Comment: In the meantime I saw @Andronicus answer. Little to add. Especially the link he gave.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, this way you are using a business id, instead of the one that is probably generated by the jpa vendor and as a result, entities, that are manages are equal to the same that aren't.

For example if we create an entity, where the id is generated by the database and save it, the following gives no error:

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
Entity savedEntity = entityRepository.save(entity); // CrudReporitory
assertFalse(entity.equals(savedEntity));
```

In most cases it's not what we want. For more details I recommend [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: Is the `professionName` really the business id? For example for Books the IBAN is definitelly global business id. And what we want in most cases? A should `equals` be burdened by "what we want in most cases"?

Comment: It's up to you to decide, you must be sure, it's going to be unique. This could be more than 1 field, for example: name, surname, age, address for person.

Answer (score 2):

You can overide the equals according to your business logic. In my case, I have excluded id.You can modify which fields are used with the lombok library:
https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode

For Example:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
public class Foo {

  private Integer id;

}
```

Comment: What happens, if the class has 100 fields? You need to make 100 comparisons to determine equality or hash the entire entity to use `HashSet`. It gets even more complicated with composition and inheritance.

Comment: The lombok generate implementations of the equals(Object other) and hashCode() methods. It will use all non-static, non-transient fields by default.

Comment: Eh. I know what lombok does, I'm saying, that your solution can negatively affect performance.

Comment: Ahh.. I'm not sure if I m getting you. If you don't want to affect the performance just include the fields you want to check for the equivalence.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant:)

Answer (score 0):

Since, there are two cases:

1. comparing two entities by equality (content)
2. comparing two entities by an identifier

You should not override `equals` to do either or. This would be confusing. Instead use a dedicated function for each. This way you/or anyone else reading the code can choose the correct one and this choice will be obvious to the reader.